# daemon function in /init.d does not run the program in the background in fedora13

Tags: fedora, daemon, background-process

I use Fedora 13 and am trying to create a service for `darkice`. I put the script in the `/etc/init.d` directory and if I use the command `service darkice start`, the `darkice` is running in the foreground and the command prompt is not returned.

How do I make `darkice` run in the background?

The following is the excerpt from the `darkice` script.

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/darkice
NAME=darkice
DESC="Darkice live audio streamer"

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0
CONFIGFILE="/etc/darkice.cfg"

# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions


# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
  start)
    # Start daemon.
    echo -n $"Starting darkice streaming daemon: "
    daemon "$DAEMON -c $CONFIGFILE > /dev/null"
    RETVAL=$?
    echo
    [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/darkice
    ;;
  stop)
```

Comment: Just for the record Fedora 13 is end of life and you should upgrade to a currently supported distribution - https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/End_of_life

Comment: I know that. I tried once to upgrade to f14 using system->Administration->software update ->Upgrade. But somehow it did not go thru all the way and failed.  Do you know of a good way that upgrades to the next distribution?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In [`man darkice`](http://www.digipedia.pl/man/doc/view/darkice.1/) there is no information about running darkice in background (daemon mode), but I found [site where init script is provided](http://wiki.radioreference.com/index.php/Live_Audio/Ubuntu_Darkice#Example_Init_Script).

Darkice is started in screen with `-d` switch that instantly detach screen. Whole command to run it looks like this:

```
DARKCONFIG="/home/drmoreau/darkice/darkice.cfg"
DARKBIN="darkice"
DARKCMD="$DARKBIN -c $DARKCONFIG"
DARKUSER="PUT YOUR LOCAL USERNAME HERE IN LOWERCASE"
SCREENEXE="screen"
SCREENOPTS="-d -m -S darkice_stream"
su "$DARKUSER" -c "$SCREENEXE"" $SCREENOPTS"" $DARKCMD"
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. Could you explain why the daemon function command does not work in the first place? Thank you very much for the link for the init script. I could not find the link you mention.  I will work on the init script and implement on my f13 to see if it works. Thank you again.

Comment: I'm not sure how function `daemon()` is built in Fedora 13, but from I found in Internet there is no code that could put process in background (detach from terminal). It is only doing few checks and start application.